# redux add property to object dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi i have a `reducer` containing one `array` of `objects`. These `objects` have some properties. When i `dispatch` an `action` in `redux` using `useDispatch Hook`  i want to add some more properties dynamically.How can i achive this thing

//reducer data

```
    users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      first_name: "JACKILINE",
      status: "online",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      first_name: "BRONNNZE",
      status: "offline",
      
     },
  ];
```

I want to add these two properties dynamically `mesg: "how are you",lastSeenDate: "30/11/19",` How can i update the state in reducer

//i want the reducer like this after dispatching an action

```
users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      first_name: "JACKILINE",
      status: "online",
      mesg: "how are you",
      lastSeenDate: "30/11/19",
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      first_name: "BRONNNZE",
      status: "offline",
      mesg: "how are you",
      lastSeenDate: "30/11/19",
     
    },
  ],
      `
```

//My action

```
export const setLastMessage = (payload) => ({
  type: actionTypes.SET_LAST_MESSAGE,
  payload: {
    id: payload.id,
    lastSeenDate: payload.date,
    mesg:payload.message
    
  },
});
```

Comment: You dont dispatch using the `useSelector` hook, you would use `useDispatch`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do, but I guess you could do it when you get `users` rather when you import it.

How do you get `users`?

Please try to do this in your slice file(maybe src/slices/user.js).

```
const initialState = {
  users: []
}
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUsers(state, action) {
      const { users } = action.payload;

      state.users = users.map(user => ({
        ...user,
        mesg: "how are you",
        lastSeenDate: "30/11/19"
      }))
    },
  }
});

export const reducer = slice.reducer;

export const getUsers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.get('/api/users');

  dispatch(slice.actions.getUsers(response.data));
};
```

Or you could do the similar thing while importing `users` in your component.

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add action creator:

```
export const ANY_ACTION = 'ANY_ACTION';

function actionFun (msg, lastSeenDate) {
   return {
      type: ANY_ACTION,
      msg,
      lastSeenDate
   }
}

export function handleActionFun (msg, lastSeenDate) {
     return (dispatch) => {
          return dispatch(actionFun(msg, lastSeenDate))
     }
 }
```

In Reducer:

```
import { ANY_ACTION } from './actionCreators';

export default function users (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ANY_ACTION :
              return state.map(u => {
                  return u.mesg = action.msg, u.lastSeenDate = action.lastSeenDate;
              })
        default :
            return state
    }
}
```

You can call it using `dispatch(handleActionFun(msg, lastSeenDate))`

Comment: Amr Eraky : I want update for a specific property

Comment: OK. you can pass any data from ```dispatch(handleActionFun({data}))``` to reducer.

Comment: Amr Eraky : can you please update your answer .How can i do that in my `reducer`.Like to update for specific `property`

Comment: I've update the answer that can update for a specific property.